# Relational databases and object oriented environment

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, language-agnostic, ado.net

As every body knows that Object oriented languages provide reusability features.

I have a simple three tier application:

1. presentation layer
2. business layer is designed to reap the benefits of reusability
3. datalayer is a dumb ado.net library(by dumb I meant that it has no business logic in place.)

I have been struggling to enforce code reusability in this datalayer. I am pasting a pseudo pattern in one of my **methods** in  datalayer.

```
create connection object
open connection to database
create a transaction object
begin transaction
create command object
execute it
.
.
.
.
create nth command object
execute it
commit transaction
close connection
```

In reality this code swells to around 300 to 400 lines of code and it becomes impossible to read this code.

In this series of command executions we are selecting / inserting / updating queries on different tables. If it were not to be in transaction, I would have separated this code to their respective classes.

There is again a spaghetti pattern which I recently encountered:

```
business layer method1 calls datalayer method to update column1 
business layer method2 calls datalayer method to update column2
businees layer method3 calls datalayer method to save the entire result in table by updating it.
```

This pattern emerged when I was trying to reap the benefits of reusability, these methods are called from different locations so they were reused. However, if were to write simple sql query not keeping in mind of reusability there would have been a single call to database.

**So, is there any pattern or technique by which reusability can be achieved in data layer?**

**Note:**

1. I don't want to use any stored procedures despite the fact that they
   offer precompilation benefits and etc. , as they tend to tie
   datalayer more specific to a particular database.
2. I am also currently not considering any ORM solutions here only
   plain ADO.net.

---

Excuses for not considering any ORMs.

1. Learning curve
2. Avoiding tight coupling to a specific ORM which I think can be
   removed by restricting the ORM code in datalayer itself.
3. I checked the internet some time 6 months ago and there were only
   two popular or widely used ORM solutions available then. Entity
   Framework and NHibernate. I choose Entity Framework (<strike>for some reasons
   I will link later</strike> [link1](http://www.dennisdoomen.net/2013/03/entity-framework-56-vs-nhibernate-3.html), [link2](http://ayende.com/blog/4351/nhibernate-vs-entity-framework-4-0) besides that I had a feeling that working with EF would be easy as it is provided by Microsoft) to start learning.
4. I used this [Microsoft recommended
   book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780735627390.do) in this book
   there were three techniques as I understood
   [TPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618293),
   [TPH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292.aspx) and
   [TPC](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx); TPC I never tried.
5. When I checked the SQL generated from the Entity Framework, it was
   very ugly and was creating some extra columns: Ids, some ugly Case
   statements etc., it seemed that for a highly transactional system
   the ORM solution cannot be applied.By highly transactional system I mean 1000 of insertions happening every single minute. The database continues to swell in size and reaches somewhere near 500 to 600 GBs in some distant future.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the only thing that comes to mind, but that's just as messy (if not messier). What is your reasoning behind not using an ORM?

Comment: "I would like someone to suggest a solution, except please do not suggest the solution that everyone would recommend.  I want a different solution."

Comment: Why not consider an ORM solution? Don't reinvent the wheel. Not only do ORM frameworks like EF and NHibernate already solve the problem you're having, they're very well documented, and have long ago solved many of the bugs you're going to encounter by trying to do it yourself

Comment: How often (and radically) are you planning to swap around your database providers that SQL presents a meaningful stumbling block to success?

Comment: If you really insist on doing it yourself for some reason, read up on generics and the Unit of Work pattern

Comment: @Jedediah I'm `dying` to know what's the OP's `excuse` for not using Entity Framework (or any other ORM)

Comment: @HighCore right? A programmer and a programmer who can get things done cleanly and in a timely manner are two really different things. A lot of programmers seem to think it's cheating or not good enough to not do everything from scratch.

Comment: ORMs are the tool of the Devil, but if you want to treat relational data as objects, you're already in Hell, so you ought to use the backhoe you're given instead of trying to build one from pitchforks and string.

Comment: @48klocs The applications we develop can have different data layer implementations, depending upon the business use case, client expectations etc. So migrating from one database to another should be easy. Also the design should be as such as it supports [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: @RyanHenderson I agree with You, dynamic SQL is the most ugliest thing that comes into mind. I will never use it even if that is the only option left in this universe :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments to your question; you should really avoid re-inventing the wheel here and go with an ORM, if at all possible.  Speaking from experience, you're going to end up writing code and solving problems that have long ago been solved and it will probably take you more time in the long run.  However, I understand that sometimes there are constraints that don't permit the use of an ORM.

Here are some articles that I have found helpful:

This first article is an old one but it explains the different options that you have for data access design patterns.  It has a few different patterns and only you can really decide which one will be best for you but it sounds like you might want to look at the Repository Pattern:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx

This next article is the first in a series that talks about how to implement a repository pattern with a data mapper which, based on your example above, will probably help to reduce some of your redundant code.

http://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.com/2010/02/data-access-layer-in-c-using-repository.html

Finally, depending on how you implement your data access pattern, you may find the template pattern and generics helpful.  The following article talks about that a little bit and you can glean some helpful information from it:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/elegant_dal05212006130957PM/elegant_dal.aspx

Without knowing more about your project, it's hard to say, exactly, which pattern will best suit your needs.  However, using a combination of the Unit of Work pattern with repositories and data mappers will probably help you to reuse some code and manage your data access.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm not seeing is your model layer.

You have a business layer, and a DAO layer, but no model.

```
business layer method1 calls datalayer method to update column1 
business layer method2 calls datalayer method to update column2
businees layer method3 calls datalayer method to save the entire result in table by updating it.
```

Why isn't this:

```
business layer updates model/domain object A
business layer updates model/domain object A in a different way
business layer persists model/domain to database through data layer.
```

This way you get re-use, and avoid repeated loops back and forth to database.

Ultimately it sounds like your business layer knows FAR too much of the database data model.  You need business *objects*, not just business methods.

Comment: I think You meant [DTOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object): which are objects that act as a carriers in cross layer talks, in this case business layer talks to data layer. Yes there is a seperate project that has all such DTOs; I have not shown here for the sake of simplicity

Comment: Also an interesting point to note here is that in some database calls from business layer, I don't require any DTO and I simply pass on some primitive data types such as int, string etc.

Comment: Can you give an example of this?   What would such a call look like?  Is it something like:  setCustomerToInactive(int custId)?

Comment: Yes that is exactly how it looks

Comment: I would change it so that was not a DAO method.  I would make your DAO just persist the inactive customer.  If there is something special about persisting an inactive customer, then you might end up having to add extra logic...  But honestly, it will simplify your code and increase your reusability by a large proportion if you make your DAO methods more coarse.  This is the same reason that other people are recommending using a JPA solution.  The DAO should know about persisting whole entities, not individual columns. Otherwise you are breaking your abstraction over your data store (slightly).

Comment: what is a JPA solution?

Comment: Sorry, language parsing issue, JPA is java's most common ORM solution, and I'm doing java work now, so I've been using JPA interchangeably with ORM recently.